# Another error in my SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, join

I am wondering about another syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_question
    WHERE category='art'
        LEFT JOIN forum_answer ON (forum_question.id = forum_answer.question_id) 
    GROUP BY forum_question.id 
ORDER BY a_datetime DESC;
```

The error I am getting is this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LEFT JOIN forum_answer ON (forum_question.id =
>   forum_answer.question_id) GROUP B' at line 1

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause should be after the `FROM` clause. `JOIN` statements are part of the `FROM` clause

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    forum_question
        LEFT JOIN forum_answer 
           ON (forum_question.id = forum_answer.question_id)
WHERE   category='art' 
GROUP   BY forum_question.id 
ORDER   BY a_datetime DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause should be after the `JOIN` clause

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    forum_question
        LEFT JOIN forum_answer 
           ON (forum_question.id = forum_answer.question_id)
WHERE   category='art' 
GROUP   BY forum_question.id 
ORDER   BY a_datetime DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

First `join`, then use the `where` clause:

```
    SELECT * FROM forum_question
    LEFT JOIN forum_answer ON (forum_question.id = forum_answer.question_id) 
    WHERE forum_question.category='art'
    GROUP BY forum_question.id 
    ORDER BY a_datetime DESC;
```

Comment: @ypercube - Because there are a lot of cowards who enjoy drive-by revenge downvoting.